# How set value in hidden input in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have hidden input in template HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="idNote" value="{{formSpam.idNote}}" ng-model="formSpam.idNote" required>
```

Also method in controller that takes one param and assigns this value to `formSpam.idNote`:

```
$scope.ClickSpam = function (id){
      $scope.formSpam.idNote = id;
}
```

But in template for attribute `value` this is empty when I send form. Why?

Completed code:

```
<div class="spam-icon ng-scope" data-dismiss="modal" ng-controller="SpamController" ng-click="ClickSpam(22, 1);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#spamModal"></div>
```

After this HTML in bottom page:

```
<div class="modal fade spam-modal" id="spamModal" ng-controller="SpamController" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<input type="hidden" name="idNote" ng-value="formSpam.idNote" ng-model="formSpam.idNote" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Typically, in a Single Page Application, one does not need to use `<input type="hidden">`, because classic form submission is not done, and instead Ajax is used. But otherwise, `value="{{formSpan.idNote}}"` should work fine - so, something else is not working in your code

Comment: Does anybody know solution?

Answer (score 5):

Use ng-value:-

```
<input type="hidden" name="idNote" ng-value="formSpam.idNote" ng-model="formSpam.idNote" required>
```

One more thing there is no need of required and ng-model on hidden field you can simply do it by:-

```
<input type="hidden" name="idNote" ng-value="formSpam.idNote">

$scope.ClickSpam = function (id){
      $scope.formSpam.idNote = id;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8adsy97/)

Comment: Hm, does not work, so maybe reason is that I have two same controllers? One `SpamController` in main template and `SpamController` in modal window?